# Stylesheet for Firefox only

Tags: css

Is it possible to mention some style elements that work only with Firefox? Can I get the same for margin elements in specific? Hope I am clear enough in my question?

Comment: Why do you need something like this?

Comment: If you need to style Firefox separately, it suggests that you have something wrong with one of your other style sheets. Do you build in Firefox and check in IE or the other way around?

Comment: One reason to style differently is web fonts can look pretty different in Firefox versus Chrome.  For me, I want to use a less-bold font for headings in Firefox than in Chrome/others.

Answer (score 3):

This great jQuery plugin can do just that!

Check out the [CSS Browser selector](http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/).

You can use a class selector in your CSS to tell it which browser to aim at:

```
.ff3 .myDiv
{
  mystyles
}
```

I use it and it works great :)

Although it should be said that if it's wrong in Firefox, it's probably some wrong coding and you should fix it without using any targeted CSS. Usually you need to fix IE, and for that you can use [Conditional Comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html).

Answer (score -2):

you can use conditional tags to specify what CSS to be used by your browser.

```
  <![if !IE]>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="${realpath}/$csspath/style_common.css" type="text/css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="${realpath}/$csspath/style_default.css" type="text/css">
    <![endif]>
```

Comment: @Knu, these conditional comments only apply to IE. So Firefox, Chrome etc will ignore the if statement entirely.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks I was talking about the link tags not the CCs.